# Не работает простетский скрипт. Parse error

Tags: php, wamp

Не судите строго. Это можно сказать мой первый скрипт, который я разбираю и тот комом. :(
Короче суть вот в чём.
Есть форма *send.html*:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="script.php" method="POST">
        Введите имя:     <input type=text name="name"><br>
        Введите возраст: <input type=text name="age"><br>
                         <input type=submit value="GO!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

И есть скрипт *script.php*:

```
<?php
echo "Привет,$_POST['name']! Вам $_POST['age'] лет !";
?>
```

Так в результате работы этого простого скрипта вылетает ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING) in E:\wamp64\www\mysite\script.php on line 2

И вот я не пойму: либо что-то в коде не правильно, либо мой веб-сервер глючит. К слову у меня сборка WAMP 64bit 3.0.6.

Comment: +1 за слово "простетский"

Answer (score 1):

Во избежание таких же ошибок в дальнейшем, лучше всего выносить все переменные за кавычки и использовать одинарные кавычки. Использование одинарных кавычек предпочтительнее с точки зрения быстродействия: интерпретатору PHP не придется искать наличие переменных (экономия "на спичках", но все же), так как в одинарных кавычках они не обрабатываются.

Если вы планируете изучать и работать с PHP в дальнейшем, старайтесь не обращаться к переменным $_POST, $_GET и подобным напрямую. Это связано с тем, что $_POST['name'] может быть не установлен и если вы настроили отображение ошибок уровня E_STRICT (весьма полезно при написании скриптов), то ошибки будут постоянно появляться. Для получения данных лучше всего использовать функцию [filter_input()](http://php.net/filter_input), с её помощью можно проверить данные на корректность, но об этом уже почитайте в документации.

Никогда не выводите данные, введенные пользователем напрямую, без обработки, на страницу. Это чревато многими проблемами, например XSS. Все данные, которые могут содержать амперсанд, кавычки, знаки меньше и больше нужно заключать в функцию [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

В итоге ваш echo может выглядеть так:

```
echo 'Привет, '.htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name')).'! Вам '.htmlspecialchars(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age')).' лет !';
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, получилось.)
Но с таким синтаксисом скрипт перестаёт быть "простетским".)

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry OnGamer, правильно отметил!
При использовании переменных в вводе, в частности в echo ""
Переменную нужно оборачивать в {$var} фигурные скобки, для того чтобы компилятор отличил ее от обычного текста.
Если вы используете двойные кавычки в echo, то обычные переменные типа $var можно и без {}. Но переменные типа массив
$var['value] нужно оборачивать в фигурные скобки.
Так же можно использовать конкатенацию
Примеры

```
echo "Привет $name"; //двойные кавычки
echo "Привет {$_POST['name]}"; //Переменная типа массив
echo "Привет " . $_POST['name']; //Конкатенация
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте фигурные скобки:

```
echo "Привет,{$_POST['name']}! Вам {$_POST['age']} лет !";
```

Comment: Этот вариант мне больше нравится!)